# Is Electorate badge working

Tags: support, badges

The Electorate badge states "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

I have 696 votes and I am just about positive over 25% of those votes are on questions and not answers.  I am also pretty sure that I have not voted on anywhere near 96 community wiki questions.

Is the Electorate tag not working/inactive currently for this site or is there some criteria that I am not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is "voted on 600 **questions**". Your 696 votes includes questions and answers. We only have 700 questions on Webmasters so I doubt you have voted on 600 of them.

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense.  That badge description came across very differently to me.  Thanks!